# Can someone identify this plant I saw in NYC (might not be native idk)

Tags: species-identification, botany

I've never seen a plant with these type of leaves before and was wondering if anyone recognized/can figure out the species.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so simple solution I saw the owner of the plant out and just asked what it was. She said it was a Konnyaku Potato (Amorphophallus konjac 'Nightstick'). You can see the branching shoot at the bottom, similar colors, and similar leaves.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it is probably a single leaf coming up from a tuber.

That fact combined with the mottled pattern on the petiole (leaf stalk) and the shape and branching pattern of the leaflets makes me guess it was something in the genus [*Amorphophallus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphophallus).

Example image: [image: *Amorphophallus konjac* aka. voodoo lily image by keithp2012]

[Other images for the "voodoo lily"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Amorphophallus%20konjac%22%20leaf&tbm=isch&source=univ&safe=off&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPiJrnnpDjAhWnct8KHTFCAwgQsAR6BAgDEAE&biw=2173&bih=1272#imgrc=oGXz7PcviFEt9M:).

Comment: please provide some evidence for *why* you think this is the case as well as a picture if you can find one in the public domain to share. I think you're correct, but your answer is not so great if your links die. We typically want the answers to provide more stand-alone evidence than yurs currently does, especially for [tag:species-identification] questions (in which many people provide incorrect IDs). Please [edit] to add this additional detail. thanks!

Comment: @forestecologist: Finally figured out how to insert an image — is this better?

Comment: Better, yes, But if you could provide a bit more detail (e.g.,what about the petiole is significant?, etc.) and a source supporting claims that *X* about the petiole (or mottled leaves, etc.) are in fact indicative of this group, your answer would be better still. Adding these types of details & references does 3 things: 1) allows you to double check yourself (especially if you haven't seen formal sources yourself), 2) provides a reader greater confidence  you're right, and 3) enables readers to easily find a (hopefully) good gateway to learning more. In other words, The extra work pays off

Comment: Thanks for the help, the actual plant was in fact of the amorphophallus genus so props on that. I'm sure we could've figured it out with some research into the genus you provided had a more direct opportunity for answers not presented itself.